# Fluentd capture stack traces from Docker

Tags: regex, docker, fluentd

I'm trying to get Fluentd to parse Java stack traces, coming from the Docker logging driver, using in_tail and emit them as a single messages.

For the life of me, can't figure out why it's still splitting them up.

This is a sample input, that's being written to a file:

```
2015-12-17T19:19:47+00:00   docker.java.ubuntu:15.10    {"log":"Exception in thread main java.lang.NullPointerException\r","container_id":"5a064eb23465350a11fe00b1f7787f5bd3e9f0182dd44c09516a72ab4006bd54","container_name":"/src-test_1.0.0.353_989549167.1","source":"stdout"}
2015-12-17T19:19:47+00:00   docker.java.ubuntu:15.10    {"container_id":"5a064eb23465350a11fe00b1f7787f5bd3e9f0182dd44c09516a72ab4006bd54","container_name":"/src-test_1.0.0.353_989549167.1","source":"stdout","log":"        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)\r"}
2015-12-17T19:19:47+00:00   docker.java.ubuntu:15.10    {"container_name":"/src-test_1.0.0.353_989549167.1","source":"stdout","log":"        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)\r","container_id":"5a064eb23465350a11fe00b1f7787f5bd3e9f0182dd44c09516a72ab4006bd54"}
2015-12-17T19:19:47+00:00   docker.java.ubuntu:15.10    {"container_id":"5a064eb23465350a11fe00b1f7787f5bd3e9f0182dd44c09516a72ab4006bd54","container_name":"/src-test_1.0.0.353_989549167.1","source":"stdout","log":"        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)\r"}
2015-12-17T19:19:47+00:00   docker.java.ubuntu:15.10    {"container_id":"5a064eb23465350a11fe00b1f7787f5bd3e9f0182dd44c09516a72ab4006bd54","container_name":"/src-test_1.0.0.353_989549167.1","source":"stdout","log":"test\r"}
```

This is the config I'm using for in_tail:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  tag docker.multiline
  path /tmp/fluent/java*
  pos_file /tmp/fluent/log.pos
  refresh_interval 10
  format multiline
  format first_line /.*\"log\":\"[^\s].*/
  format /\"log\":\"(?<message>.+)\\r/
</source>
```

The regexes look correct to me and when I plug them into a regex tester, the first_line regex only matches the first and last lines of my sample, while the format regex matches every line, but only captures the stack trace info, as I'm expecting. However, they're all coming out as separate messages, almost like first_line is matching every line, instead of the first and last.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/parser_multiline, the config keys should be `format_firstline` and `format` (rather than `format first_line` and `format`).